# Buy or make assets

Tags: unity, blender, 3d-modeling

As an indie developer, I don't know if I should make my own models or buy them from the asset store (unity engine). I do know basic modeling in Blender, but I also have spare money that I can use to buy assets.

Another doubt I have is that if I decide to make my own models or assets. Is it good to sell them in the asset store (unity engine) or just keep the assets to myself?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what you want.

Any answer but that would probably be subjective, but I'll try to elaborate anyhow:

I enjoy making games because it lets me get creative. I can make my own models, animate them, and place them in a 3d world. I like being able to say I made the entire game. But if you find it difficult to do all that, or just think it takes too much time while you'll never make something as beautiful as the asset you found (believe me, I know that struggle), there's nothing wrong with using assets.

Also, if you are good at modeling, texturing, animating, but realize your games don't work out because you're a terrible programmer, you could sell your models as assets. Your models would help other people finish their games, and seeing your models out there in the real world, in a finished game, is awesome.

Bear in mind that there have been made so many poorly written games created solely with assets from unity's store, that whenever you make an asset-filled game, people get hesitant. Their first idea will most likely be that it's probably terrible. Don't think buying assets will allow you to release your game sooner. Buying assets will allow you to spend more time on gameplay, story, and all other things you're making by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple cost-benefit analysis.

- How much money per hour do you value your worktime?
- How many hours will it take you to create asset X?
- How much money will it cost you to buy asset X?

This, of course, assumes that you:

1. have the skills to create the asset yourself in the desired quality and
2. that you find an asset in the store which is exactly what you want.

If only one of these is true, the choice is obvious. If neither is true, there is a third option: Hire an artist to create it for you.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. When you use assets, you'll never get exactly what you would have made and vice versa. So the quality of the game changes with that. And with that, your revenue does as well (if you insist on looking at finances)